# Search for a string with in a module in a python file using Python

Tags: python, file, copy, line

```
#!/usr/bin/env python`
import sys`
import binascii`
import string
sample = "foo.apples"
data_file = open("file1.py","r")
dat_file = open("file2.txt", "w")
for line in data_file:
    if sample in line:
        dat_file.writelines(line)
 dat_file.close()`
```

When I do this I am able to find the string foo.apples. The problem is `foo.apples` is present in various lines in the python file. I want those lines which are inside a particular function. I need the lines within this def function.

`Example:`

```
def start():
    foo.apples(a,b)
    foo.apples(c,d) ... so on.
```

Comment: Do you mean `function`?  In python, the entire file is the module ...

Comment: oh ok then I mean the function. Like def start() function.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish at a high-level? I.e., _why_ do you want to find `"foo.apples"` only inside functions? There might be a better solution to your real problem besides a text search.

Comment: I am trying to get the hex values in foo.apples which is actually foo.apples(hex1, hex2). The file1.py has a function `def start():` which has multiple lines with foo.apples(hex1, hex2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following program finds `def`s and will append the sample string to the output file if the indentation remains within the `def`.

```
import re

sample = 'foo.apples'
data_file = open("file1.py", "r")
out_file = open("file2.txt", "w")
within_def = False
def_indent = 0

for line in data_file:
    def_match = re.match(r'(\s*)def\s+start\s*\(', line)  # EDIT: fixed regex
    if def_match and not within_def:
        within_def = True
        def_indent = len(def_match.group(1))
    elif within_def and re.match(r'\s{%s}\S' % def_indent, line):
        within_def = False

    if within_def and sample in line:
        out_file.writelines(line)

out_file.close()
data_file.close()
```

Tested working on an example `file1.py`.

Comment: Okay so this is returning values in all def. So I have the `sample` present in other def :-(

Comment: @Ram Sorry I misinterpreted your question.  I edited the answer (see `# EDIT` line) to work correctly to find only `foo.apples` within `def start` indentation levels.

Answer (score 0):

One, slightly off the beaten path approach to this would be to use the `getsource` method of the `inspect` module.  Consider the following (theoretical) `test1.py` file:

```
class foo(object):
    apples = 'granny_smith'
    @classmethod
    def new_apples(cls):
        cls.apples = 'macintosh'

def start():
    """This is a pretty meaningless python function.
    Attempts to run it will definitely result in an exception being thrown"""
    print foo.apples
    foo.apples = 3
    [x for x in range(10)]
    import bar as foo
```

Now you want to know about the `start` code:

```
import inspect
import test1  #assume it is somewhere that can be imported

print inspect.getsource(test1.start)
```

Ok, now we have only the source of that function.  We can now parse through that:

```
for line in inspect.getsource(test1.start).splitlines():
    if 'foo.apples' in line:
        print line
```

There are some advantages here -- python does all the work of parsing out the function blocks when it imports the file.  The downside though is that the file actually needs to be imported.  Depending on where your files are coming from, this could introduce a **HUGE** security hole in your program -- You'll be running (potentially) "untrusted" code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very non pythonic way, untested, but it should work.

```
sample = "foo.apples"
infile = open("file1.py", "r")
outfile = open("file2.txt", "w")
in_function = False

for line in infile.readlines():
    if in_function:
        if line[0] in(" ", "\t"):
            if sample in line:
                outfile.write(line)
        else:
            in_function = False
    elif line.strip() == "def start():":
        in_function = True
infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

I would suggest doing a function of this, which takes `sample`, the input file, and the function which we're supposed to search from as it's parameters. It would then return a list or tuple of all the lines that had the text in them.

```
def findFromFile(file, word, function):
    in_function = False
    matches = []
    infile = open(file, "r")

    for line in infile.readlines():
        if in_function:
            if line[0] in(" ", "\t"):
                if word in line:
                    matches.append(line)
            else:
                in_function = False
        elif line.strip() == "def %s():"%function:
            in_function = True

    infile.close()
    return matches
```

Comment: Hi Mahi Thanks. I guess the first one you suggested was something similar to the state machine working and I am trying to find the post here about that which someone had mentioned. The thing is it did not work when I gave def start():  when I tried to do this yesterday. I will try again now.

Comment: Make sure you call with only "start" like so: `findFromFile("test.txt", "foo.apples", "start")`